# How to filter arrays and objects by path while keeping the structure intact

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am developing a JSON API which is running on PHP 7.2.  One of the API features is a basic "only show me these columns" filter.  I would like to be able to make this dynamic without having to manually handle each "level" in the path.

My first approach was to only support a nested path five levels deep.  This covers most use cases, and it has worked well for a few years.

/api/request/stuff?column=col1-sub1-data2,col1-sub2

Full structure (could be an object or an array, but I can cast to array if necessary):

```
[
  'col1' => [
    'sub1' => [
      'data1' => false,
      'data2' => 'abc',
      'data3' => 123
    ],
    'sub2' => [
      'other1' => true,
      'data3' => 987
    ]
  ],
  'col2' => [
  ]
]
```

Here is an example of my very naive approach:

```
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    $path = explode('-', $column);

    if (!is_array($path) || empty($path)) {
        continue;
    }

    $pathCount = count($path);

    switch ($pathCount) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            /* Too shallow. These should be handled before this point anyway... */
            continue 2;
        case 2:
            if (!isset($detailObject[ $path[ 0 ] ][ $path[ 1 ] ])
            ) {
                continue 2;
            }

            $newArray[ $path[ 0 ] ][ $path[ 1 ] ] = $detailObject[ $path[ 0 ] ][ $path[ 1 ] ];
            break;
        case 3:
            if (!isset($detailObject[ $path[ 0 ] ][ $path[ 1 ] ][ $path[ 2 ] ])
            ) {
                continue 2;
            }

            $newArray[ $path[ 0 ] ][ $path[ 1 ] ][ $path[ 2 ] ] = $detailObject[ $path[ 0 ] ][ $path[ 1 ] ][ $path[ 2 ] ];
            break;
    }
}
```

With the column parameter, the API processes the data and returns the following:

```
[
  'col1' => [
    'sub1' => [
      'data2' => 'abc'
    ],
    'sub2' => [
      'other1' => true,
      'data3' => 987
    ]
]
```

Is there a way to dynamically produce this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing operations on nested structures of arbitrary depth pretty much always calls for a recursive function.

```
function filterPath($data, $path) {
    $key = array_shift($path);
    if( empty($path) ) {
        return [$key => $data[$key]];
    } else {
        return [$key => filterPath($data[$key], $path) ];
    }
}

function filterPaths($data, $paths) {
    $out = [];
    foreach($paths as $path) {
        $out = array_merge_recursive($out, filterPath($data, $path));
    }
    return $out;
}

$data = [
  'col1' => [
    'sub1' => [
      'data1' => false,
      'data2' => 'abc',
      'data3' => 123
    ],
    'sub2' => [
      'other1' => true,
      'data3' => 987
    ]
  ],
  'col2' => [
  ]
];

var_dump(
    filterPaths($data, [
        ['col1', 'sub1', 'data1'],
        ['col1', 'sub1', 'data3'],
        ['col1', 'sub2'],
        ['col2']
    ])
);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["col1"]=> array(2) {
    ["sub1"]=> array(2) {
      ["data1"]=> bool(false)
      ["data3"]=> int(123)
    }
    ["sub2"]=> array(2) {
      ["other1"]=> bool(true)
      ["data3"]=> int(987)
    }
  }
  ["col2"]=> array(0) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your explanation!